# Laravel 5.2 MethodNotAllowedHttpException with Patch on route::resource

Tags: forms, routes, crud, laravel-5

I want to update a post. Creating and deleting a post works perfectly but whenever I try to update it with a PATCH form, it fails and gives a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

My routes.php:

```
...
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
...
```

Which gives me the following list of possible routes (pasted in css to keep it readable):

```
| GET|HEAD  | posts                    | posts.index          | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index   
| POST      | posts                    | posts.store          | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store    
| GET|HEAD  | posts/create             | posts.create         | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@create     
| GET|HEAD  | posts/{posts}            | posts.show           | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@show        
| DELETE    | posts/{posts}            | posts.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@destroy        
| PUT|PATCH | posts/{posts}            | posts.update         | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@update      
| GET|HEAD  | posts/{posts}/edit       | posts.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@edit
```

My edit.blade.php (url= localhost:8000/posts/1/edit):

```
 {!! Form::model($post, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['PostsController@update', $post]]) !!}
        @include('posts/_form', array('submitText' => 'Update'))
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And my PostsController:

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post) {
        $post->update($request->all());
         return Redirect::route('posts.index')->with('message_succes', 'Post updated');
}
```

Whatever I try, it fails with a

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in
>   RouteCollection.php line 206

Looking at the html source of the form the PATCH and token is inserted properly.
When changing the PATCH to post in the form, it will use the store function and creates a new post. What do I need to do to update the post?

Comment: You should pass only an id with form action. You used `$post`. As you you didn't share `edit()` method, we don't know what returns in `$post` variable. If $post is a collection, use `['PostController@update',$post->id]`. If not work, please share the `edit()` method's code.

Comment: @smartrahat Yes you're right. Already found out that I was indeed posted the complete object. It's working now.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I was posting the complete object and not only the ID.
I had to change:

`$post` to `$post->id` in the form and the PostController update to:

```
  public function update(Request $request, $post_id) {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($post_id)
        $post->update($request->all());
         return Redirect::route('posts.index')->with('message_succes', 'Post updated');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the PATCH method to put in the form like this :

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method' => 'PUT', 'action' => ['PostsController@update', $post]]) !!}
    @include('posts/_form', array('submitText' => 'Update'))
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It gives me the same error. Another thing to say is that the fields are not populated with the entries.

Answer (score 0):

For those, who just forgot to specify action/route for edit form, i.e.:

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method' => 'PATCH']) !!}
    ...
    Form controls
    ...
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

If you don't explicitly specify `update` form action on `edit` page, `Form::model()` would use current route, e.g. `<site>/posts/<id>/edit`. So, don't forget about real `update` action location, either via route:

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['posts.update', $post]]) !!}
    ...
    Form controls
    ...
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

... which I personally prefer, 'couse it's more universal, or via action:

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['PostsController@update', $post->id]]) !!}
    ...
    Form controls
    ...
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

... which is slightly over-verbose and specific.

Answer (score -1):

Nice, you're correct ! but you commented reverse, $post->id to $post then the controller will use the entire object instead the single. Now worked here. Thanks!